# How to combine & and &&?

Tags: shell-script

This is the type of question which is very hard to search for!

I have a shell script that goes like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
./script.fcgi --socket /tmp/fcgi-socket &
sleep 2
chmod a+w /tmp/fcgi-socket
```

script.fcgi is a long running programm (a daemon?) and I need to append the & in order to have it run in the background. Beside the fact that I am tired, I need sleep because otherwise the script does not have time to set up the socket before I can chmod it.

I wanted to have a one-liner like this:

```
./script.fcgi --socket /tmp/fcgi-socket & && chmod a+w /tmp/fcgi-socket
```

but I guess it's not possible. And I don't know how to get the script to set the socket with the proper write permissions (that would be for another question). But I was curious: am I missing something about combining & and && or it's really not possible to do what I have in mind?

Comment: Why don't you set permission in fpm config? And why do you want it world writable?

Comment: `script & { sleep 2; chmod; }`.  Or just `umask 000; script`.

Comment: Note that literally combining `& and &&` doesn't make sense, because `&` puts the first command in the background before it exits, but `&&` needs the first command to exit to determine its exit status.  So you need to combine `&` and `;`.

Comment: Combining & and the "if it succeeds do this" && concept is possible, for a process that will eventually end & return a success/failure code. But in your particular socket problem with an unending process I think you'll never really know when your socket is ready, unless you modify the `script.fcgi` to tell you when it's ready... or if it does the `chmod` itself as a "ready" message...

Answer (score 3):

Assuming I understand what it is you want to do and your process is not prone to forking, I'd do something like:

```
/long/running/process with args &
LRP_PID=$!
sleep 2
if jobs %% #It's alive!
then 
    chmod a+w ...
fi
```

(Or `kill -0 $LRP_PID` instead of `jobs 1`.)

Comment: Best answer IMO. Could you explain `kill -0`, though? I can't find a reference to a `0` signal. Are you just trying to send some kind of "dummy signal" to see if the process still exists? (not sure if that's a good idea, if the behavior of `kill -0` is unspecified)

Comment: @MalteSkoruppa there's no 0 signal, but I'm pretty certain that for both kill the command and kill the system call, 0 as a signal spec is used to check if a signal can be delivered, which can be taken to mean the process is still alive.

Comment: @MalteSkoruppa ah yes. From [`man 3 kill`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/kill.3posix) (Ubuntu POSIX manpages): "If sig is 0 (the null signal), error checking is performed but no signal is actually sent. The null signal can be used to check the validity of pid."

Comment: Note that `kill -0` will fail if the process is still alive but has changed to a different UID (unless the `kill` runs as `root`).

Comment: @Scott so using job control commands might be the better way, I suppose.

Answer (score 2):

Yes of course it is possible: this is the syntax

```
 (/absolute/path/to/script/script.fcgi --socket /tmp/fcgi-socket &) && (sleep 2; chmod a+w /tmp/fcgi-socket)
```

But keep in mind Mikel's comment, which is correct.

EDIT:

in view of @muru's comment below, let me explain. The OP does not want to execute the 2nd and 3rd commands upon successful completion of the first one: he explicitly states that it is a long-running command. The OP wants to execute the third command upon successful *start* of the first command. The one-liner above does exactly this.

EDIT2:

At @muru's prompting, the following one-liner will check for errors in the start-up of the initial commands:

```
 (/absolute/path/to/script/script.fcgi --socket /tmp/fcgi-socket  2> /path/to/errors.txt &) && (sleep 2; if ! [ -s /path/to/errors.txt]; then chmod a+w /tmp/fcgi-socket; fi)
```

Comment: This offers no benefit at all over `/.../script.fcgi --socket /tmp/fcgi-socket & sleep 2; ...`, does it?

Comment: @muru you have a mistake in your syntax, perhaps a missing *;*. The (very small) benefit is that it executes the second half provided the subshell is correctly branched. Like I said, Mikel's comment is correct, but at leat the above syntax does what the OP asked.

Comment: nope, no mistake in my command.

Comment: Actually, that claim does not hold either. Try: `(non-existent-command &) && (echo yes)`

Comment: @muru I did: it executes the echo provided the *non-existent-command* is correctly branched, that's all. Once branched, that the command exists or not does not matter: the branching has been executed successfully, hence the echo is executed. As per my post.

Comment: which is pointless, since when does a subshell fail to branch in any modern shell?

Comment: @muru Now, after conceding that there is nothing wrong with the above one-liner, you are restating Mikel's point, with which I agreed from the start.

Comment: I think you and i are reading different things. I don't think you're construction is wrong, just that it's pointless, since it offers no benefit at all over what OP already has. Mikel's point is that such constructions in general are pointless.

Answer (score 0):

If you won't be logging out of the terminal, you can run it this way:

`./script.fcgi --socket /tmp/fcgi-socket && chmod a+w /tmp/fcgi-socket &`

If you are going to log off, then its better to start the script under a terminal multiplexer like `screen` or `tmux`.

I am not very familiar with `tmux`, but this is how you can do it with `screen`:

Start a screen, using the `screen` command. In the new 'screen' shell, start:

`./script.fcgi --socket /tmp/fcgi-socket && chmod a+w /tmp/fcgi-socket`

Hit `enter`

Detach from the screen by pressing `ctrl + a` followed by `ctrl + d`

You can connect back to the screen after you come back using:

`screen -r`

Running this script under screen, will run the script in the background. You will be able to connect back to that shell when you re-attach to the screen.

Answer (score 0):

You can put a process (or several processes) in the background with `&` and then later in your script you can wait for them all to finish, using the bash builtin `wait` command. Here's it's blurb from `man bash`:

```
   wait [-n] [n ...]
          Wait for each specified child process and return its termination
          status.  Each n may be a process ID or a job specification; if a
          job spec is given, all processes  in  that  job's  pipeline  are
          waited  for.  If n is not given, all currently active child pro‐
          cesses are waited for, and the return status is zero.  If the -n
          option  is  supplied,  wait  waits  for any job to terminate and
          returns its exit status.  If n specifies a non-existent  process
          or  job, the return status is 127.  Otherwise, the return status
          is the exit status of the last process or job waited for.
```

Checking `wait`'s return status for a specific job can provide the "if successful" check that `&&` does, as in this test script:

```
#!/bin/bash
sleep 3 &
s3pid=$!
true &
trpid=$!
false &
fapid=$!

echo "Expecting success next, since true returns 0"
wait $trpid && echo "wait process true success" || echo "wait process true FAIL"
echo "Expecting FAIL next, since false returns 1"
wait $fapid && echo "wait process false success" || echo "wait process false FAIL"
echo "Expecting success next, since wait alone always returns 0"
wait && echo "wait for all success" || echo "wait for all FAIL"
```

But for just one command, using `&&` alone would be the same... And in the asker's case if you're running a "never stop" daemon type program it won't be ending & you don't really want `&&` or `wait`

Comment: Will that work in a script? Isn't job control weird when not in the interactive mode?

Comment: I've used it successfully in a script to launch multiple `wget &`'s and a plain `wait` at the end to tell me when they've all finished & ready for processing. (I don't like the multiple "n" vs "-n" usage in the man page, unnecessary confusion)

Comment: Downvote? Seriously? Is there something that's *"egregiously sloppy, no-effort-expended post, or an answer that is clearly and perhaps dangerously incorrect"* about using `wait` to almost literally combine & and &&?

Comment: @Xen2050 somebody down voted all the posts here, so don't take it too hard. Probably a random troll.

Comment: @muru Thanks. It seems like drive-by downvoting happens more often on unix&linux than on superuser, askubuntu, others... Maybe the mouseover description  should be changed from "not useful", since it's *very* different from what the help pages say about downvoting (part quoted in comment above)

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that a lot of people are overthinking this. 
It's enough to say

```
./script.fcgi --socket /tmp/fcgi-socket & sleep 2; chmod a+w /tmp/fcgi-socket
```

because, *syntactically*, `&` acts like `;`. 
(Yes, of course, I know that they are *semantically* different.)

Comment: This is what OP already has.

Comment: @muru: Where? I see `& &&` in the question where my answer has only `&`. (Also, the question says "I have `cmd1 &` (newline) `cmd2` and I want to make it a one-liner.)

Comment: The first code sample that OP shows is exactly this, except OP uses newlines. Calling this a one-liner because OP used newlines and you didn't is disingenuous.

Comment: (1) Absolutely! I copied the code from the question's first code block, pasted it into my answer, deleted the newlines, and added the semicolon after the `sleep 2`. (2) I disagree that my claim is disingenuous. AFAICT, the OP doesn't understand that `cmd1 &` and `cmd2` (separate lines) can be combined into `cmd1 & cmd2` _without adding any intervening punctuation, such as `;`_, and that that is exactly what the question is asking. Maybe I misunderstand the question, but I'm not trying to pull a fast one.